# How to use Attachment Image from Table in Access Form and Report Headers?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms, ms-access-reports

I have an Access database used by many projects and each project have its logo and information stored in table called `company_info_tb`.

I stored the logo in Attachment field type; each project can modify its info and logo to be used in its printed reports.

How I can call the project logo to be shown in the headers of Access forms and reports using a Bound Object Frame or another way?

I tried using `dlookup` in the Control Source of the Bound Object Frame:

```
Dlookup("LOGO","company_info_tb")
```

And using `LOGO` that was shown in mainform, by putting this code in the Control Source:

```
=forms!main_frm!LOGO
```

But it doesnt work.

Comment: Is this an all-in-one db (not split into frontend/backend)? Split or not - each project runs an independent copy of db?

Comment: I think showing logos on forms is unnecessary window dressing. Serves no practical purpose.

Comment: Its an all-in-one db, I need the logo to show in printed reports.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. include logo attachment field table in report RecordSource, without a join clause the logo record will associate with each record of data table/query (Cartesian relationship), place bound control only in header section - not appropriate for data entry/edit form because the resulting query is not updatable
2. save the logo image externally and store path in text field then use DLookup expression or Cartesian query
3. subform/subreport in header

Recommend using Image control and set its ControlSource property either by binding to attachment field or text field or expression to construct external path. A BoundObjectFrame control must be bound to an OLEObject field and options 1 or 3 would work.

Comment: so DLookup doesn't work with image and attachments as texts, if I wanna use attachments it should be in the query source to be able to use it or using image path.